# Accessing self from outside of a class

Tags: python, decorator

I'm attempting to implement a decorator on certain methods in a class so that if the value has NOT been calculated yet, the method will calculate the value, otherwise it will just return the precomputed value, which is stored in an instance `defaultdict`. I can't seem to figure out how to access the instance `defaultdict` from inside of a decorator declared outside of the class. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Here are the imports (for a working example):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import sqrt
```

Here is my decorator:

```
class CalcOrPass:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.f = func

    #if the value is already in the instance dict from SimpleData,        
    #don't recalculate the values, instead return the value from the dict
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # can't figure out how to access/pass dict_from_SimpleData to here :(
        res = dict_from_SimpleData[self.f.__name__]
        if not res:
            res = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
            dict_from_SimpleData[self.f__name__] = res
        return res
```

And here's the SimpleData class with decorated methods:

```
class SimpleData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.stats = defaultdict() #here's the dict I'm trying to access

    @CalcOrPass
    def mean(self):
        return sum(self.data)/float(len(self.data))

    @CalcOrPass
    def se(self):
        return [i - self.mean() for i in self.data]

    @CalcOrPass
    def variance(self):
        return sum(i**2 for i in self.se()) / float(len(self.data) - 1)

    @CalcOrPass
    def stdev(self):
        return sqrt(self.variance())
```

So far, I've tried declaring the decorator *inside* of SimpleData, trying to pass multiple arguments with the decorator(apparently you can't do this), and spinning around in my swivel chair while trying to toss paper airplanes into my scorpion tank. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't have a good answer to your question, but shouldn't `defaultdict` live in the decorator rather than in the `SimpleData` instance ? I don't see why `SimpleData` should know about what seems to be a implementation detail from the decorator (which would also solve your problem).

Comment: Hmmm that might work. I need to have a different default dict for every instance of SimpleData, however...

Comment: On a side note: Always inherit your classes from `object` when coding in Python 2. Not doing so, gives you "old style" classes that have a different behavior than what might be expected.

Comment: What you want is a simple memoizing decorator. Don't reinvent the wheel -- use one that's already written, or at least do it the standard, simpler way -- as in the answer you _didn't_ select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you define your decorator the target object information is lost. Use a function wrapper instead:

```
def CalcOrPass(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def result(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self.stats[func.__name__]
        if not res:
            res = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.stats[func.__name__] = res
        return res
    return result
```

`wraps` is from `functools` and not strictly necessary here, but very convenient.

---

Side note: `defaultdict` takes a factory function argument:

```
defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

But since you're testing for the existence of the key anyway, you should prefer a simple `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want when your function is defined, because it is unbound. Here's a way to achieve it in a generic fashion at runtime:

```
class CalcOrPass(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.f = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None): # Cheat.
        return self.__class__(self.f.__get__(obj, type))

    #if the value is already in the instance dict from SimpleData,
    #don't recalculate the values, instead return the value from the dict
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # I'll concede that this doesn't look very pretty.
        # TODO handle KeyError here
        res = self.f.__self__.stats[self.f.__name__]
        if not res:
            res = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
            self.f.__self__.stats[self.f__name__] = res
        return res
```

A short explanation:

- Our decorator defines `__get__` (and is hence said to be a *descriptor*). Whereas the default behaviour for an attribute access is to get it from the object's dictionary, if the descriptor method is defined, Python will call that instead.
- The case with objects is that `object.__getattribute__` transforms an access like `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`
- This way we can access the bound class and its type from the descriptor's parameters.
- Then we create a new CalcOrPass object which now decorates (wraps) a bound method instead of the old unbound function.
- Note the new style class definition. I'm not sure if this will work with old-style classes, as I haven't tried it; just don't use those. :) This will work for both functions and methods, however.
- What happens to the "old" decorated functions is left as an exercise.

Comment: You could also, if you have Python 2.6 or later, use a class decorator, then go through all the class attributes and bind a caching function for them (or look for ones marked by another decorator and bind just those).  But that's a huge pain. :-)

Comment: @torek: a caching function? is that just a memoization function?

Comment: This one actually turned out to be more tedious to implement than the other answer. That being said, this answer was exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @JoelCornett: yes, although "memoizing" tends to be used for functions with arguments and in this particular example the argument (`self.data`) is implied and unchanging.